# How do I login silently to multiple web applications without user being interrupted to keep their sessions active

Tags: java, c#, vbscript

We need to login to 20 - 30 different web applications and enter credentials to keep user active throughout the day. This needs to happen in the background on user's machine without user being interrupted. What technology do we use here to achieve this?

We thought of using an RPA but this is intrusive and causes user interruption. User will be locked out of using their machine while RPA is running.

We expect this automated code to login to multiple web application one at a time or in a parallel thread (no preference) throughout the day on a schedule or user can kick this off. This automated solution needs to be able to hold user credentials and keep user free from entering their credentials.

Can we use C#, vbscript, java or any other software development tool to achieve this type of effort?

Comment: Consider asking on http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: Have you considered Selenium?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime - I have never used Selenium, I would love to know more about it and how to implement the solution. Do you happen know how cost effective would it be?

Comment: @DavidBrossard: this would be off-topic on [security.se]: either it will be seen as not related to security at all (i.e. off-topic) or it would be seen as an attempt to bypass existing security measures in the form of the session timeout (off-topic too).

Comment: The requirement is not fully clear for me: if this is something which just must prevent the session timeout so that the user can continue at any time without logging in again then it must likely run inside the users browser to get access to cookies, local storage, have same browser fingerprint etc. It might also need to be adapted to the specific web application.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Current requirement is to run a script/automation/solution that logs in to multiple applications silently without interrupting user. We're trying to figure out different ways to do it. We can use an RPA but it takes control of user screen and disrupts their work. I'm thinking something along the lines of a web crawler.

Comment: @user1100941: It is still not clear. Why does it need to run on the users PC if it just automates stuff? It can run anywhere then (cloud etc). And for example Chrome can be run in headless mode, Firefox could be run inside some virtual display (XNest) etc.

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible. The biggest issue you will likely face is that different websites may use different mechanisms for authentication, but most could probably be generalized.

Here's a simple single-threaded example in Python, but any language could be used and concurrency could be implemented.

```
import requests
import re


# Put the configuration for each website in a structure like this
websites = [
    {
        'url': 'https://example.com/login',
        'form': {'username': 'myusername', 'password': 'password123'}
        'csrf_token': {'regex': '<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="(.*)">', 'post': 'csrf_token'},
        'check': 'Welcome, myusername!',
    },
    {
        'url': 'https://example2.com/login.php',
        'form': {'username': 'myotheruser', 'password': 'qwertyuiop'}
        'csrf_token': {'regex': '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="(.*)">', 'post': '_token'},
        'check': 'My Account',
    },
    ... more websites
]

for website in websites:
    # Use sessions so cookies are preserved
    session = requests.Session()

    # If the website requires CSRF tokens, we need to fetch the login page first to extract the token
    if website.get('csrf_token'):
        r = session.get(website['url'])
        csrf_token = re.search(website['csrf_token']['regex'], r.text).group(1)
        # Update post params with CSRF token value
        website['form'][website['csrf_token']['post']] = csrf_token
    r = session.post(website['url'], data=website['form'])

    # Check if login worked
    if website['check'] in r.text:
        print("Successfully logged in to:", website['url'])
    else:
        print("Failed to log in to:", website['url'])
```

Note that this example makes some naive assumptions about CSRF tokens, nor does it implement error handling. Hopefully this gives you an idea.

Comment: Great response @multithr3at3d ! Thank you very much. I'll try this out and let you know how it goes.